# Bower package registry is not picking up the latest release/tag

Tags: registry, version, bower, publish

I have published a package in the Bower registry:
http://bower.io/search/?q=angular-order-object-by

And its repo:
https://github.com/fmquaglia/ngOrderObjectBy

I have cut a new release a few dayds ago: https://github.com/fmquaglia/ngOrderObjectBy/releases/tag/1.3

For some reasons that is eluding me even after creating and pushing the tag `1.3` and making a release with it, when I run locally `bower cache clean` and `bower info angular-order-object-by` I just get older versions listed, but not the new one:

`(...)
Available versions:
  - 1.2.1
  - 1.1.1
  - 1.1.0
  - 1.0.0
(...)`

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've done this before, but I just don't get it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It was a pretty evident problem with the tag and semver.

The tag should be `1.3.0` rather tah `1.3`.

That's pretty much it.